# JQuery: Equal Heights not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to equalise the heights of some content in a div. When I load the page, it looks like this:

[image: Setting all heights to the FIRST (and smallest) element]

I get this output in the console:

```
Content loop no.0
177
Content loop no.1
177
Content loop no.2
177
DONE
```

In the above output im logging the heights of each element when they loop. However, the second and third elements are 203px tall, not 177. When I resize my browser window, it corrects itself, and all works as expected. When I set breakpoints and step through the code, it works as expected. It only seems to happen when I refresh my browser???

I'm trying to only equalise the heights if the column is NOT full width.

Here is my code:

```
var c,
    Cards = {
        //Settings
        settings: {
            row: $('.row'),
            card: $('.card')
        },

        //Initialising Function
        init: function() {
            c = this.settings;
            this.resizeCard();
        },

        resize: function() {
            c = this.settings;
            this.resizeCard();
        },

        resizeCard: function() {

            // Reset height
            $('.card-content').css('height','');

            // Iterate through each "Row" element
            c.row.each(function(i) {

                var rowWidth = c.row.width(),
                    columns = $(this).find('.grid-column'),
                    cards = $(this).find('.card'),
                    contentHeight = 0;

                // If there's more than one card in this row...
                if(cards.length > 1) {
                    // Iterate through each column, check the width
                    columns.each(function() {
                        if(rowWidth > $(this).outerWidth()) {// If the card is in a row of cards
                            $(this).find('.card').addClass('equal-height'); // Add the equal height class
                        }
                    });
                }

                // Iterate through each content div under "Equal Height" cards
                $(this).find('.equal-height .card-content').each(function(i) {
                    console.log("Content loop no." + i)

                    if($(this).height() > contentHeight) {
                        contentHeight = $(this).height();
                    }

                    console.log(contentHeight)
                })

                // Set the final height of the content
                if(contentHeight > 0) {
                    console.log("DONE");
                    $(this).find('.equal-height .card-content').css('height',contentHeight);
                }


            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the script in the page? I would suggest adding it to the bottom right before the `</body>` tag

Comment: Hey mate, yeah it's at the bottom before the closing body tag.

Comment: Is it in a document ready function? any console errors?

Comment: try using `.outerHeight('true')` instead of `.height()`?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No console errors. Yeah this function (resizeCard) is called in a document ready AND window resize.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the same problem occurs with this.

Comment: Is this a bootstrap page? if so, you can make all the divs in this row the same height by just using css

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No, this is something I've developed myself.

Comment: Have you tried initializing on $(window).load? (or .on in 3.0)?

Comment: I'm still reading,  but it looks like you might be setting your card heights too early.

Comment: That appears to 'kind-of' worked.... thanks for your help!